# AngularJS Help: Connecting a Search Input into an REST Interface

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I been studying AngularJS for last few days, however I'm stuck on one section. What I want to do is by allowing the user to input a search (within the input widget of course), I want the search to be connected to Online API (OpenWeatherAPI) and extract JSON data from online. I then want the result to be displays within the webpage.

I already done the source code for extracting JSON data using AngularJS. I'm just stuck on connecting the search query to the API. Here the source code for the extracting the REST API:

```
9 var app = angular.module('oMoonShine', []); 
10 

11 // Note: Controller To Access Weather Data From OpenWeatherAPI (Content Type: JSON)  
12 app.controller('FetchController', function ($scope, $http) { 
13     $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139", request) 
14     .then(function (response) { 
15         if (response.status == 200) { 
16             // Note: Important To Print Your Response To Anaylse The JSON Recieved 
17             // Note: For Example OpenWeatherAPI Add Additional Param So Have it 
18             // Note: Like <code>$scope.info = response.data;</code> To Anaysle It 
19             $scope.info = response.data; 
20         } 
21     }); 
22 

23     // Note: Request Object For Extra Types 
24     var request = { 
25         headers: 'application/json', 
26         method: 'GET' 
27     }; 
28 });
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? No data displayed? An error message?

Comment: Basically connecting the input of search into REST API. So let say I'm searching for Japan. I input it into a search box and then click submit. The word Japan then get added to the URL of the API then I received the information back. What I'm stuck on is basically when I click the "Submit" button, getting that connected to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you access the data:
A working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinaidoron/j7dyaezg/2/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   The weather from {{weatherLocation}}
    <p>The wind speed is: {{windSpeed}} and the degree is {{windDegree}}</p>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);


function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139").success(function(data){
    $scope.weatherLocation = data.name;
    $scope.windSpeed = data.wind.speed;
    $scope.windDegree = data.wind.deg;

        console.log(data)
    }) 
}
```

**Edit**

After reading your comments, see my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinaidoron/j7dyaezg/3/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   The weather from {{weatherLocation}}
    <p>The wind speed is: {{windSpeed}} and the degree is {{windDegree}}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="location"/>
    <button ng-click="findWeather()">submit</button>
</div>

angular.module('myApp',[]).controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);


function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.location = "";

    $scope.findWeather = function(){
    http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=washington
            $http.get(" http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $scope.location).success(function(data){
    $scope.weatherLocation = data.name;
    $scope.windSpeed = data.wind.speed;
    $scope.windDegree = data.wind.deg;

    }) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I can do that section, what I mainly looking for is connecting what I submit to the URL which I'm stuck on. Basically when I press the submit button, it put whatever I type into the URL

Comment: Can you give an example on how you want the url to look like and what data you get from the text box? because I don't see a name of location in the url

Comment: OK, the URL look like this:

Comment: Thank that I want, I'm sorry about not putting the correct URL in the last comment as my computer just froze when I was halfway typing. Thank for your help

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please up vote and accept the answer, thanks